# Access Mono/Flux Context in @ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

is there a way to access the ContextView object of a Mono/Flux in an `@ExceptionHandler`?

Here is my simplyfied code:

```
@RestController
class Endpoint {

   @Autowired
   private Service service;

   @GetMapping
   Mono<String> get() {
      return service.doStuff() // this throws an exception
          contextWrite(context -> context.put("debug_information", "XYZ"));
   }
}
```

Now I would like to access the "debug_information" during the exception handling, in order to log it.

I would like to it like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler {
   @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
   public Mono<ResponseEntity> handleException(Exception ex) {
      return Mono.deferContextual(contextView -> Mono.just(contextView.get("debug_information")))
          .map(s -> {
              logger.log(s)
              return ResponseEntity.status(500).build();
       }  
   }
}
```

Unfortunately `@ExceptionHandler` does not allow for `Mono<>` as return type, so this does not work.

What would the correct way to access `ContextView`?

Comment: you could access your debug info n the reactive context and pass it along the exception instead

Comment: actually that's what I am doing right now, but I was hoping to decouple these two things.

Comment: Then mention that in your question so we dont sit here and put time into something ”you are already doing” good luck

Comment: my question is: "is there a way to access the ContextView object of a Mono/Flux in an @ExceptionHandler?". NOT: "how to forward additional information to @ExceptionHandler?".

Comment: Easy answer, no